# Target specific container to close in Javascript in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to have my close function (deleteRecipe) `.fadeOut` the container surrounding it and not the bottom container(currently happening). 
Once closed, I want to be able to click the `undoButton` to `.fadeIn` what was `.fadeOut` in deleteRecipe

JavaScript

```
var main = function () {


var mainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('mainContainer');
var backGroundPic = document.createElement("IMG");
backGroundPic.setAttribute("src", "../images/cutting_board.png");
backGroundPic.setAttribute("class","backgroundPic");
$('body').append(backGroundPic);


var recipeArray = ['drink', 'firstCourse', 'mainDish', 'dessert'];
var recipeArrayLength = recipeArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < recipeArrayLength; i++) {

    var $container = $('#container');
    var $contentContainer = $('<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="contentContainer"></div>');
    $($container).append($contentContainer);

    var $checkBoxesContainer = $('<div class = "checkBoxesContainer"></div>');
    var $recipePicContainer = $('<span class = "recipePicContainer"></span> ');

    function makeRecipePic() {


        var $recipe = $('<IMG class="recipe">');
        $recipe.attr('src', '../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg');
        $($recipe).css('margin-top', '10px');
        $($recipePicContainer).append($recipe);
    }

    var $deleteRecipe = $('<span class="fa fa-times-circle aria-hidden true"></span>');
    $($checkBoxesContainer).append($deleteRecipe);


    $deleteRecipe.on('click', function () {
        $($contentContainer).fadeOut()
        $($undoButton).fadeIn()
    });

        //
        //$($deleteRecipe).click(function () {
        //    $(this).find(contentContainer).fadeOut();
        //    $($undoContainer).fadeIn();
        //});

    makeRecipePic();

    var $undoContainer = $('<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="undoContainer"></div>');
    $(mainContainer[0]).append($undoContainer);

    var $undoButton = $('<button class="fa fa-undo aria-hidden true"></buton>');
        $($undoContainer).append($undoButton);
        $($undoContainer).hide();



    $undoButton.on('click', function () {
        $($contentContainer).fadeIn();
        $($undoButton).fadeOut();
    });

    //$($undoButton).click(function(){
    //    $(contentContainer).fadeIn();
    //    $($undoContainer).fadeOut();
    //});

    $(mainContainer[0]).append($contentContainer);
    $($contentContainer).append($checkBoxesContainer);



    var $div = $('<div></div>');
    $div.innerHTML = 'CockTails';
    $($recipePicContainer).append($div);
    $($checkBoxesContainer).append($recipePicContainer);

    var $recipes = $('<ul class = "recipes"></ul>');
    //var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkBoxes');

    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

    for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = "ingredients";
        li.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");


        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.innerHTML = "Ingredient " + j;

        li.appendChild(a);
        $($recipes).append(li);
    }
    var b = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
    li.className = "Instructions";

    $($checkBoxesContainer[i]).append($recipes);
}
$($recipes).hide();
$('<input type="checkbox" value="1" />').prependTo(".ingredients");
$('.recipePicContainer').click(function () {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');

});

};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Whats your html?

Comment: can you please provide html of your page, Issue might be happening  because of undobutton inside the container you are fading out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DanDaManEker/d53nr5y6/1/

Answer (score 1):

A few things I'd note:

You can actually create elements via jQuery, which can also be used to save those in memory in a single step, like so:

```
var $container = $('<div class="container"></div>')
```

`.find()` traverses the DOM a linear way. If you want to go both ways, use `.closest()`, but then again, if you've declared all your variables wrapped in jQuery when creating the elements, this step can be avoided.

In your case you could also try to get the parent, via `$(selector).parent()`, but again, that would not be needed if you've saved everything into variables upon creating.

You final code could look something like this:

```
var $container = $('#container')
var $contentContainer = $('<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"></div>')
$container.append($contentContainer)

// ... same for checkboxes area
var $deleteRecipe = $('<span class="fa fa-times-circle"></span>')
var $undoButton = $('<button>Undo</button>')

$checkboxes.append($deleteRecipe)

$deleteRecipe.on('click', function () {
    $contentContainer.fadeOut()
    $undoButton.fadeIn()
})
$undoButton.on('click', function () {
    $contentContainer.fadeIn()
    $undoButton.fadeOut()
})
```

Comment: so worked around your example all day and it's not working. may I send you a fiddle?

Comment: Just update the question. Maybe someone else will help out before me.

Comment: When you select a DOM Node with jQuery, you create a special jQuery Object instance, which will have all the DOM manipulation methods jQuery can do. Instead of instantiating a new one each time, just use the variables you've saved: `var $element = $('.element'); $element.hide()`, instead of wrapping it again, like you do: `$($element)`

Comment: ok, I kind of started all over cuz it got really broken, but I don't mindy doing this again if it'll work